MariaDB Performance Degradation After Brief 20 Hour Massive Improvement
Problem
On 2024-05-07 20:00:00 we migrated our DB from MariaDB 10.5 on an 8 core 16GB RAM server with a 10GB innodb buffer pool to a MariaDB 10.11 server with 16 cores 32GB RAM and a 20GB buffer pool via a mysqldump logical backup and restore process.
We have 11.7GB of data and 11.5GB of indexes, totalling ~23.2GB.
For 20 hours after the migration, we immediately saw excellent performance improvements. Our database powers our HTTP API, and we were seeing around 3x faster API responses which lasted for nearly an entire workday. This was totally out of the norm and we were very happy to see this.
At 2024-05-08 16:45:00 we began to see performance begin to sharply degrade, returning to nearly the same response times that we saw before the DB migration.

my.cnf config
[mysql]

# CLIENT #
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
default-character-set          = utf8mb4

[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
default-storage-engine         = InnoDB
socket                         = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pid-file                       = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
bind-address                   = *
server-id                      = 1
report_host                    = master1

character-set-client-handshake = 0
character-set-server           = utf8mb4
collation-server               = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                = 32M

# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet             = 128M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000
skip-name-resolve

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING #
binlog-format                  = ROW
log-bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days               = 7
sync-binlog                    = 1
binlog_do_db                   = ebdb_v2

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 64M
max-heap-table-size            = 64M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 201
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 1K
table-open-cache               = 2K
max_statement_time             = 3600
join-buffer-size               = 4M
sort-buffer-size               = 4M

# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-file-size           = 2G
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 2
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 20G

# LOGGING #
log-error                      = /var/log/mysql/error.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 1
slow-query-log                 = 1
slow-query-log-file            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log

# SSL/TLS #
ssl_cert                       = /etc/mysql/certificates/server-cert.pem
ssl_key                        = /etc/mysql/certificates/server-key.pem
ssl_ca                         = /etc/mysql/certificates/ca.pem

# PERFORMANCE MONITORING #
userstat                       = 1

# EXTRA CUSTOM VARIABLES #
innodb_ft_min_token_size = 1

Areas investigated
CPU Load

CPU Load remained normal before and after.
Swap
The server does have a 512MB swap partition with default vm.swappiness (60).

However it was already at 100% before the degradation.
Swap Activity seemed higher before the degradation than afterwards
Hourly Logical Backups
Every hour we perform backups directly on the server via mysqldump - the dump takes 3 minutes and the gzipping takes around another 10 minutes.

During the backups I can see an increase in made_young buffer pool page changes.
The hourly backups had ran 20 times before the degradation and only last 3 minutes so I am unsure if they are the cause, especially with the default innodb_old_blocks_time of 1000.
Buffer Pool Read Requests & Write Requests

This is our buffer pool read requests before and after. The spikes around 00:00 are some inefficient reporting scheduled jobs that get performed nightly (retrieving a lot of the same data every night).
Write requests seem same before and after
Buffer Pool Pages

Buffer Pool Disk Read Ratio

This is innodb_buffer_pool_reads / innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests
Buffer Pool Page Changes

I can see higher lru_freed operations and made_not_young operations before the degradation compared to afterwards
Other
buffer_pool_wait_free has consistently been 0
Checkpoint Age has never came close to Max Checkpoint Age
I can't attach any more images but Disk Read Bytes has remained the same before and after - the only spikes we have is every hour when the gzipping is occurring (reading from the 13GB .sql file)
The mysql_global_status_innodb_pages_read seems a bit more consistently higher before the performance degradation than afterwards

Any hints in your slow query log? log_slow_verbosity=full and log_slow_min_examined_row_limit to 1000 to 10000 could be a good way to reduce some noise from log-queries-not-using-indexes,

There are a lot of slow queries, but they seem to be happening all the time, even during the time where performance was improved overall


Do avoid a lot of unnecessary I/O in
mysqldump ... > dump.sql
gzip dump.sql > dump.zip

do
mysqldump | gzip > dump.zip


Decrease innodb_buffer_pool_size in hopes of avoiding swapping.  (Swapping is terrible for performance.)

Use the SlowLog to discover the "worst" queries.  Improving them are likely to help with response time and diminishing swapping.

innodb_ft_min_token_size = 1 -- This sounds risky.  (I don't have experience with it, so I can't say for sure.)

For more analysis:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning



Thanks Rick, we do currently have a 512MB swap partition that we are looking to set vm.swappiness to 0 or 1 to prevent using. Would this eliminate the need to decrease innodb_buffer_pool_size like mentioned?
Along with the slow log we've recently enabled performance schema so there are a lot of queries we are coming across that are slow, not using indexes, doing full scans, or examining many rows and returning very few. We're going to start chipping away at these.

Most interestingly, we restarted the DB recently and saw the exact same performance improvement.
From 19:15:00 to 14:00:00 our performance improved massively, after 14:00:00 it dipped back.
Does the fact that it improves after a restart make you think of any other potential causes?
